# Accessing part of Json response from Postman with query string parameters

Tags: api, testing, postman

[image: Screenshot]

I only want to access faqid 44 from the json response, I've read the documentation of postman. But they tell that with query string paramaters I can do that. But I'm getting the full json response. Please help

I've also tried host/api/faq/1 -> This also doesn't work

Comment: That depends on what the API you're calling supports. Does it even support filtering using query params or otherwise?

Comment: Like Vasan has mentioned, that's the implementation of the API and nothing to do with the way that Postman works.

Comment: Thank you. you both are right. I just talked to the developer and they said that we don't support filtering using query string Paramaters.